# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition and Spring slow reload with Spring DevTools

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I know IDEA CE doesn't have support for Spring, but I still can develop with decent support for autocompletion, which is enough for me.

The issue I have is that it takes 5 to 7 seconds for the IDE to reload the server with the changes I made after hitting Ctrl + S. So, I searched for more options I can modify, and I tried these:

[image]

But it doesn't solve the issue.

While I know I can use VSCode since the Java support is excellent and with Spring the reload is very fast, for Kotlin support there is no extension good enough. So I'd like to find a fix to reduce the delay of the server restart, if possible. It seems to be done on purpose to force you to buy the Professional edition.

Comment: This information is not enough to understand the problem. Do you mean that .class files are updated on disk after 7 seconds or that Spring app is reloading after 7 sec while the changed classes appear faster than that? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the exact steps to reproduce would be nice to have. There is certainly nothing in IntelliJ IDEA Community that would specifically slow it down to force you buy the Ultimate. It's open source under Apache 2.0 license and you can try finding the code that does it (you won't).

Comment: Spring reloads after 7 seconds. To reproduce, create a new project and use IDEA. And if it's not with the IDE, why do things go much faster and better on VSCode for the same project? :/

Comment: It may depend on how the project is configured and what dependencies are in pom.xml, so please provide a link to the GitHub project that will reproduce a problem.

Comment: You can just create a new project from Initializr. I do not have anything beyond that. It doesn't even have anything but the Web dependency...

Comment: Bah. I will just go with Eclipse for it at least seems to have good support for Kotlin as well and also doesn't have any delay upon saving. It's all on IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use automatic compilation or DevTools for IntelliJ IDEA Community or Ultimate to hotswap classes in Debug mode. If you want to compile on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, assign this shortcut to `Build` | `Build Project` action (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap | Main Menu | Build | Build Project, right click, [Add Keyboard Shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmJ6D.png)).

IDE will hotswap the changed classes and the changes will be available in the browser in less than a second:

[image: Reload]

Sample project: [boot-hotswap-demo.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2tbcbwgglfdsv9/boot-hotswap-demo.zip?dl=1).

Steps:

1. Click **Debug** button to start the app
2. Open http://localhost:8080/ in the web browser
3. Observe `Greetings from Spring Boot!!!` output
4. Change the string in `HelloController.java` to something else
5. Build | Build Project (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> if you assigned it to this action)
6. Reload the page in the browser, observe the changes in less than a second, IDE shows a notification about reloaded classes.

You can also uncomment the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency in `pom.xml` if you want to rely on the DevTools and it will trigger the server restart on changes. It's a bit slower, but certainly not 5-7 seconds as you describe.

Comment: Thank you. I already knew about building it, too. Sorry for I've forgotten to mention it, but I do have a question regarding this. Wouldn't it be costly to do in larger projects?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Build action is fast and fully incremental. Also it's no different from what automatic compilation would do for you.

Comment: I downloaded your demo source but it's not working. waste my time!!! 

Comment: This is not solving my issue.  I modified a variable in my application.properties file and I dont get message that "x classes have been reloaded" as suggested in answer but "could not resolve configuration property myUrl" which is the property I changed in my application.properties file.  My pom.xml has spring-boot-devtools in it and I intend to keep it as other devs prefer using eclipse where it works fine and hot reloading is fast and works.

Answer (score 0):

We use 2 annotation processors in our project:
annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
and
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok".

Lombok works fine. But if spring-boot-configuration-processor is active - hot swap always reload all classes, that takes more than minute on my project, much faster to restart app completely.

I comment that processor before start when I need hot swap.