# Project not reloading/rebuilding when using Spring Boot Devtools

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I followed the steps to enable auto project rebuilding/reloading for IntelliJ:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my build.gradle file, I have:

```
compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
```

From what I can tell, this should be all that is needed.

I'm testing it with the following code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Huh, interesting... doesn't seem to be reloading at all??");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

I'll change the text being printed out, save the file, and I won't see any activity in the 'run' tab in IntelliJ.

If I load '/' in my browser, I see the same text being printed out in the run tab (`System.out.println`), so it's not picking up any changes.

I've restarted IntelliJ, clicked the 'refresh' icon for gradle, still not reloading when a code change is saved.

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm on a Mac with an M1 chip.

Edit: I've tried everything, having to click this button each time is going to drive me insane!!!

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are not delegating to Gradle: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png.

Comment: On my end those settings were set to 'Gradle', and I've changed them to IntelliJ IDEA. I'm still not seeing any rebuilding or changes in the console output.

Comment: See if my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416076/104891 helps.

Comment: Weird... that doesn't work for me either. I have IdeaVim installed as a plugin, maybe that's causing an issue?

Comment: Does Build | Build Project work? What if you just bind Ctrl+S to Build action?

Comment: I see it flash in the status bar "building..." with a progress bar, and then I reload the page, and don't see any changes. Super weird. I'm changing the String passed to `System.out.println()` in the '/' endpoint, and after selecting "Build | Build Project" and refreshing the page, the same text is appearing in the console, unchanged.

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to click the 'reload' button each time... that sucks.

Comment: Did you try Spring Boot run configuration type in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: I haven't, not sure I want to pay for ultimate. I decided to give Spring Tool Suite a try (eclipse) and it works beautifully. I really appreciate your help though, thx.